# How to retrieve Json from Oracle DB in spring boot

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot

I store Json as Clob in Oracle with a stored procedure using JDBC Template. Now I want to retrieve it from DB while calling from controller. How can I solve it? Which data type use to retrieve it? Should I create a field for inner fields of json as well? Because now I only hava one field for "entry" as Clob data type. Here is what I want to get:

```
{
data1:smth //I retrieved it
data2: smth //I retrieved it
entry: [ // Having trouble retrieving it
        entry1: {here is json data as well}
        ...
       ]
}
```

Comment: My suggestion. Retrieve it as a String and then convert it to JSON.

Comment: @RuiCosta When I am Casting it to String. It has an error that Clob can't be cast to String. What am I doing wrong? Here is the example what I am doing :final var = (String) (res.get("entries"));

Comment: @RuiCosta If so, is there any example? Thanks

Comment: Does this help : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-convert-a-clob-type-to-string-in-java , it's for MYSQL but may solve your problem

Comment: @RuiCosta According to tutorial, if I convert Clob to String will it be shown as Json?

Comment: If you want `JSON` as an object after, you need to convert the `STRING` into `JSON` https://www.javatpoint.com/how-to-convert-string-to-json-object-in-java
You need to do it in 2 steps 1st CLOB-> STRING 2nd STRING-> JSON